# Question on implementing cqrs/saga with Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, cqrs, event-sourcing, saga

I am studying cqrs and would like to implement the saga pattern to handle distributed transaction using Kafka.

A saga would subscribe the domain event from other aggregate to send a command. My problem is the domain event would be handled by the aggregate event handler as well.

If the aggregate event handler handled the event successfully, the offset would be committed so that the job in the broker gone.

Let's say if the aggregate event handler handle that event successfully, but the saga is not triggered because of some unexpected issue. Since the job is gone, the event would never be picked up by the saga if they both live in same consumer group...

So does it make sense to have a consumer group for the aggregate and create another consumer  group for the saga?

Comment: "My problem is the domain event would be handled by the aggregate event handler as well." - What is this aggregate event handler and what does it do?

Answer (score 0):

> so that the job in the broker gone.

I think you're misunderstanding that consuming messages from a Kafka topic does not remove them.

Part of your saga flow should be an action for committing the full offset trace once each service does its complete action

> does it make sense to have a consumer group for the aggregate and create another consumer group for the saga?

It makes sense to have intermediate topics, sure. You could use Kafka Streams processors to easily implement that